# Decrypt sqlite3 database file from Android on another system

Tags: encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

I make encrypted file on Android system. I have the key for the database.

I tried to decrypt the Android database on my Mac system using `sqlcipher`. However, it cannot open the file.

Is there a way to open encrypted database file from other system?

Comment: Its not obvious where you are having trouble. Can you explain the trouble you are having? Did you get an error during the `open`? If so, what did you try and what was the error?

Comment: What version of SQLCipher was used when it was created on the Android device?  What version of the SQLCipher command line shell are you using on your Mac to open the database?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SQLCipher uses:

•AES-256 in CBC mode

You aren't clear on which versions of the software you were using.  Are you using the command line?  Or are you opening the database in an Xcode project?  I see some notes about SQLCipher using Apples' CommonCrypto framework, but I doubt Android has access to that.

You might need to build a custom version with a different Crypto provider that can decipher the android version.